# remove unwanted parameters in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
Parameters: {
  "artist"=>{
    "photos_attributes"=> {
       "0"=>{"id"=>"96", "description"=>"", "upload_on_facebook"=>"0"}, 
        "1"=>{"id"=>"97"}
     }, 
     "professional_nickname" => "testing",
     "authenticity_token"=>"xyz", 
     "utf8"=>"✓", "id"=>"testing"
   }
}
```

In my photo show page I delete one of photo from photo album. photo successfully deleted by using ajax (also it's remove from table). but after then I submit for update description for others image then it's comes error.

```
Couldn't find Photo with ID=97 for Artist with ID=31
```

I delete this record but I my params it show that Id.

**My controller update action**

```
if @artist.update_attributes(params[:artist])
   flash[:notice] = "Artist record been updated successfully"
   redirect_to admin_artists_url
else
   render :edit
end
```

After delete with ajax how can I remove this "1"=>{"id"=>"97"} from parameters. I am using semantic_form_for.

Comment: You're not deleting the hidden input rails adds for the id of the nested record

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are couple of ways:

1. On creation you can simply remove html block with js.
2. If you want to control deletion from your view (on creation or updation) you can add hidden field (or checkbox or what you want) to your html with name artist[photos_attributes][1][_destroy] with value true.
3. If in controller you know wich element you want to delete you can write params[:artist][:photos_attributes].delete('1') before updating attributes.

Answer (score 1):

`params[:artist]` is just a hash so you could do the following:

`params[:artist][:photos_attributes].delete('1')`

Comment: You should write params[:artist][:photos_attributes].delete('1') on line before if @artist.update_attributes(params[:artist])

Answer (score 1):

After deleting the record with ajax, it should also remove the corresponding HTML block in the page.